# How to analyze data from the Internet with R to find discrepancies?

Tags: r

I am new to "R"; I have this html table [here](http://www.cronos.est.pr/test.html)

I need to find out if there is a gap in the "time (DT)" column of more than one minute. I need to analyze the data and create a new table with just two columns, the first one with the time and the second one with the number of the gap.

Like this: [output](http://www.cronos.est.pr/output.html)

So far I am able to download the data!!!

```
require(XML)
u='http://cronos.est.pr/test.html'
tables = readHTMLTable(u)
datatest=tables[[1]]
View(datatest)
```

What's next???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `lubridate` package.

```
library(lubridate)
minutes = minute(datatest[,"Time (DT)"])
gaps = c(0, diff(minutes))
output = data.frame("date_time" = datatest[,"Time (DT)"], gaps = gaps)
```

The output is like you requested except that every gap is recorded, not just the ones greater than 1 minute. To get just the big gaps, do

```
output[output$gaps > 1,]
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert the first column to `"POSIXct"` class, take differences and replace differences of one minute or less with NA.  No packages are used.

```
with(datatest, { 
  Time <- as.POSIXct(`Time (DT)`)
  Diff <- c(0 , c(diff(Time, units = "minutes")))
  data.frame(Time, Diff = ifelse(Diff <= 1, NA, Diff))
})
```

giving:

```
                  Time Diff
1  2010-01-01 09:10:00   NA
2  2010-01-01 09:11:00   NA
3  2010-01-01 09:12:00   NA
4  2010-01-01 09:13:00   NA
5  2010-01-01 09:17:00    4
6  2010-01-01 09:18:00   NA
7  2010-01-01 09:19:00   NA
8  2010-01-01 09:20:00   NA
9  2010-01-01 09:22:00    2
10 2010-01-01 09:24:00    2
11 2010-01-01 09:25:00   NA
12 2010-01-01 09:26:00   NA
13 2010-01-01 09:38:00   12
14 2010-01-01 09:39:00   NA
15 2010-01-01 09:40:00   NA
```

Comment: I have this error:    [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 89672 rows ] Can I save the output in a .csv file???

Comment: That's not an error.  It's just tellling you that it is not printing out the whole thing since it is unlikely you want to do that given the size.  Suggest you assign the result to a variable: `outDF <-  with(...etc...)`